Why Webclient will throw read time out exception like calling second request after 10 mins for the first request
Spring boot version is 3.3.5 and in the configure here is how I implement it originally
@Bean
public WebClient jsonApiWebClient() throws IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
    final ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(mapper)))
        .build();
    SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().protocols("TLSv1.2").build();
    //@formatter:off

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
        .create()
        .secure(ssl -> ssl.sslContext(sslContext))
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 20 * 1000)
        .doOnConnected(
            conn ->
                conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(35))
                    .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(35))
        );
    //@formatter:on
    return WebClient.builder().defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies).build();
}

Then I build the war the file, deploy to the tomcat instance. In my project I use webclient to call third-party api. Same request, the first time OK, then 10 mins later I call again and I will get Caused by: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException, and when I check the debug log, after the 1st success then log will show something like
2024-11-12 at 12:03:26.534 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider 259 debug - [9af1cc63, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] Channel cleaned, now: 0 active connections, 1 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.

which I assume because that request already finished and make it to inactive.
Then 10 mins later, I call the same request again, the debug log will become like this...
2024-11-12 at 12:18:15.721 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider 259 debug - [9af1cc63, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] Channel acquired, now: 1 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
2024-11-12 at 12:18:15.722 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] Added decoder [ReadTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, ReadTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2024-11-12 at 12:18:15.722 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] Added decoder [WriteTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2024-11-12 at 12:18:15.722 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] Handler is being applied: {uri=https://api.ackroo.net/cardholder/balance.json?cardnumber=637738768443606413, method=GET}
2024-11-12 at 12:18:15.722 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] onStateChange(GET{uri=/cardholder/balance.json, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x9af1cc63, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443]}}, [request_prepared])
2024-11-12 at 12:18:15.724 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] onStateChange(GET{uri=/cardholder/balance.json, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x9af1cc63, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443]}}, [request_sent])
2024-11-12 at 12:18:50.756 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] WARN  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect 304 warn - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 - R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] The connection observed an error io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null
2024-11-12 at 12:18:50.771 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 ! R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] Channel closed, now: 0 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
2024-11-12 at 12:18:50.771 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 ! R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] Non Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(ReadTimeoutHandler, [id: 0x9af1cc63, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 ! R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2024-11-12 at 12:18:50.772 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 ! R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] Non Removed handler: WriteTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(WriteTimeoutHandler, [id: 0x9af1cc63, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 ! R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2024-11-12 at 12:18:50.773 EST [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider 259 debug - [9af1cc63-2, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 ! R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443] onStateChange(GET{uri=/cardholder/balance.json, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x9af1cc63, L:/192.168.162.68:44864 ! R:api.ackroo.net/130.211.7.112:443]}}, [disconnecting])
2024-11-12 at 12:18:50.769 EST [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-31] ERROR com.itsp.epp.service.AckrooServiceImpl 288 processTransaction - OUTBOUND request timeout on 10 org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: null
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://api.ackroo.net:443/cardholder/balance.json [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4576) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:205) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:229) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:279) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.maybeOnError(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:327) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:212) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.drain(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:476) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor$EmitterInner.drainParent(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:620) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PubSubInner.request(FluxPublish.java:874) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$DeferredSubscription.request(Operators.java:1743) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:196) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:205) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onUncaughtException(HttpClientConnect.java:403) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.22.jar:1.1.22]
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onUncaughtException(ReactorNetty.java:708) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.22.jar:1.1.22]
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:223) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.22.jar:1.1.22]
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:476) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.22.jar:1.1.22]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:247) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.22.jar:1.1.22]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:468) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.22.jar:1.1.22]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:514) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.22.jar:1.1.22]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:153) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.22.jar:1.1.22]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.readTimedOut(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:98) ~[netty-handler-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.channelIdle(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:90) ~[netty-handler-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$ReaderIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:525) ~[netty-handler-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AbstractIdleTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:497) ~[netty-handler-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:156) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:408) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) [?:?]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:104) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1779) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
        at com.itsp.epp.service.AckrooServiceImpl.processTransaction(AckrooServiceImpl.java:210) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.itsp.epp.service.AckrooServiceImpl.balanceInquiry(AckrooServiceImpl.java:115) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.itsp.epp.controller.GiftCardController.inquiry(GiftCardController.java:120) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at com.itsp.epp.aop.TenantInterceptor.logInboundRequest(TenantInterceptor.java:76) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:637) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:71) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.proceed(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:269) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:264) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:197) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringMethodInterceptor.invoke(DeferringMethodInterceptor.java:44) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at com.itsp.epp.controller.GiftCardController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.inquiry(<generated>) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:145) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
        at ...
Caused by: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException

At this point the read time out already exists...
And the way I fix it is ... build a ConnectionProvider with pendingAcquireTimeout to 5s and maxIdleTime to 30s, and change to HttpClient.create(provider), that way works, no time out any more because after 10 mins it will create a new pooled channel?
